# Scala: Type parameters and inheritance

Tags: scala

I'm seeing something I do not understand.  I have a hierarchy of (say) Vehicles, a corresponding hierarchy of VehicalReaders, and a VehicleReader object with apply methods:

```
abstract class VehicleReader[T <: Vehicle] {
...

object VehicleReader {
  def apply[T <: Vehicle](vehicleId: Int): VehicleReader[T] = apply(vehicleType(vehicleId))

  def apply[T <: Vehicle](vehicleType VehicleType): VehicleReader[T] = vehicleType match {
    case VehicleType.Car => new CarReader().asInstanceOf[VehicleReader[T]] 
    ...
```

Note that when you have more than one apply method, you must specify the return type.  I have no issues when there is no need to specify the return type.

The cast (.asInstanceOf[VehicleReader[T]]) is the reason for the question - without it the result is compile errors like:

```
type mismatch;
 found   : CarReader
 required: VehicleReader[T]
    case VehicleType.Car => new CarReader()
                                  ^
```

Related questions:

- Why cannot the compiler see a CarReader as a VehicleReader[T]?
- What is the proper type parameter and return type to use in this situation?

I suspect the root cause here is that VehicleReader is invariant on its type parameter, but making it covariant does not change the result.

I feel like this should be rather simple (i.e., this is easy to accomplish in Java with wildcards).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem has a very simple cause and really doesn't have anything to do with variance. Consider even more simple example:

```
object Example {
  def gimmeAListOf[T]: List[T] = List[Int](10)
}
```

This snippet captures the main idea of your code. But it is incorrect:

```
val list = Example.gimmeAListOf[String]
```

What will be the type of `list`? We asked `gimmeAListOf` method specifically for `List[String]`, however, it always returns `List[Int](10)`. Clearly, this is an error.

So, to put it in words, when the method has a signature like `method[T]: Example[T]` it really declares: "**for any** type `T` you give me I will return an instance of `Example[T]`". Such types are sometimes called 'universally quantified', or simply 'universal'.

However, this is not your case: your function returns specific instances of `VehicleReader[T]` depending on the value of its parameter, e.g. `CarReader` (which, I presume, extends `VehicleReader[Car]`). Suppose I wrote something like:

```
class House extends Vehicle

val reader = VehicleReader[House](VehicleType.Car)
val house: House = reader.read()  // Assuming there is a method VehicleReader[T].read(): T
```

The compiler will happily compile this, but I will get `ClassCastException` when this code is executed.

There are two possible fixes for this situation available. First, you can use existential (or existentially quantified) type, which can be though as a more powerful version of Java wildcards:

```
def apply(vehicleType: VehicleType): VehicleReader[_] = ...
```

Signature for this function basically reads "you give me a `VehicleType` and I return to you an instance of `VehicleReader` **for some** type". You will have an object of type `VehicleReader[_]`; you cannot say anything about type of its parameter except that this type exists, that's why such types are called existential.

```
def apply(vehicleType: VehicleType): VehicleReader[T] forSome {type T} = ...
```

This is an equivalent definition and it is probably more clear from it why these types have such properties - `T` type is hidden inside parameter, so you don't know anything about it but that it does exist.

But due to this property of existentials you cannot really obtain any information about real type parameters. You cannot get, say, `VehicleReader[Car]` out of `VehicleReader[_]` except via direct cast with `asInstanceOf`, which is dangerous, unless you store a `TypeTag`/`ClassTag` for type parameter in `VehicleReader` and check it before the cast. This is sometimes (in fact, most of time) unwieldy.

That's where the second option comes to the rescue. There is a clear correspondence between `VehicleType` and `VehicleReader[T]` in your code, i.e. when you have specific instance of `VehicleType` you definitely know concrete `T` in `VehicleReader[T]` signature:

```
VehicleType.Car -> CarReader (<: VehicleReader[Car])
VehicleType.Truck -> TruckReader (<: VehicleReader[Truck])
```

and so on.

Because of this it makes sense to add type parameter to `VehicleType`. In this case your method will look like

```
def apply[T <: Vehicle](vehicleType: VehicleType[T]): VehicleReader[T] = ...
```

Now input type and output type are directly connected, and the user of this method will be forced to provide a correct instance of `VehicleType[T]` for that `T` he wants. This rules out the runtime error I have mentioned earlier.

You will still need `asInstanceOf` cast though. To avoid casting completely you will have to move `VehicleReader` instantiation code (e.g. yours `new CarReader()`) to `VehicleType`, because the only place where you know real value of `VehicleType[T]` type parameter is where instances of this type are constructed:

```
sealed trait VehicleType[T <: Vehicle] {
  def newReader: VehicleReader[T]
}

object VehicleType {
  case object Car extends VehicleType[Car] {
    def newReader = new CarReader
  }
  // ... and so on
}
```

Then `VehicleReader` factory method will then look very clean and be completely typesafe:

```
object VehicleReader {
  def apply[T <: Vehicle](vehicleType: VehicleType[T]) = vehicleType.newReader
}
```

Comment: I had also tried the placeholder in the return type (i.e. an existential) but that then results in requiring the return values to be cast, as you note.  I will explore your second suggestion - it does strike me as correct - thanks much.

Comment: @ScalaNewb, I have explained the second approach in more detail.